# Bootstrap .table-responsive blocks me the page scrolling in Android Cordova iFrame

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, iframe

I have an iframe in a Cordova app for Android, displaying a webpage with bootstrap tables which have the class="table-responsive".

The scrolling in the Android app is blocked when I try to scroll with my fingers (touch) above the responsive tables. So, I have to scroll through the little margins left by the table to scroll the page.

I want to enable the scrolling of the page above the tables.

This is the code for that in bootstrap.css

```
.table-responsive {
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;       
  }
```

[image]